# Round number to only first decimal place

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to know the available phone memory, so I wrote this code.

```
File path2 = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat2 = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize2 = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
double result = availableBlocks * blockSize;

free = (Preference)this.findPreference("free_mem");
free.setSummary(Double.toString(result)+" GB");
```

The problem is that I get a outpout as 5.654707363. I tried to take only the first decimal place using

```
free = Math.round(size * 10) / 10d;
```

But doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "It doesn't work" will never get you an answer: you have to specify what the result actually was, and why it was unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question right you need `NumberFormat` here:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
nf.format(5.654707363);
```

produces **5,7**

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value for display purpose, use `NumberFormat` (see answer by Adam Arnold).

For numeric rounding (producing the rounded number), use `BigDecimal`:

```
double num = 3.141592653589793d;
double rounded = BigDecimal.valueOf(num).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `free = Math.round(free * 10) / 10d;` instead of `free = Math.round(size * 10) / 10d;`?  I don't see `size` as a defined variable.

A simple test of

```
double free = 5.654707363;
free = Math.round(free * 10) / 10d;
System.out.println(free);
```

outputs 5.7.

Comment: Yes i tried 

double result = availableBlocks * blockSize;
result = Math.round(result * 10) / 10d;

But doesn't work... The outpout is always 5.654707363