# Round number with Math round: doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

I wish I could understand how it is possible that is not rounded the decimal number obtained from the following code.

```
File path2 = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat2 = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize2 = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
double result = availableBlocks * blockSize;

free = (Preference)this.findPreference("free_mem");
free.setSummary(Double.toString(result)+" GB");
```

In a code similar to this use this instruction and works

```
result = Math.round(result * 10) / 10d;
```

Why not work here and I still see a number with many decimal places?

Comment: Maybe because you `/ 10` ... Example: `Math.round(1) / 10` = 0.1

Comment: So you're trying to remove decimals? Are you looking for behavior similar to `Math.Floor()`?

Comment: Deja vu. I've seen a question like this today and it had the same error.

Comment: @AdamArold just checked his profile, it's because he posted it twice today.

Comment: My bad. I did not check the names.

Comment: @Vallenti, For what number should I divide?
Sorry if I posted twice but the other question I have not found the solution to my problem. Sorry again.

Comment: So this is an exact duplicate. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question right you need `NumberFormat` here:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
nf.format(result);
```

This produces a number with 1 decimal places.

So if `result` is `6.6789` it will produce `6.7`.

Related: [Round number to only first decimal place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247311/round-number-to-only-first-decimal-place/20247374#20247374)

***Just a note:***

If you do this:

```
Math.round(result * 10) / 10d;
```

you basically say:

1. Multiply `result` with 10
2. Round the result
3. Then divide with ten.

When you got rid of the decimals at step 2. you got another bunch of decimals after the division.

Comment: I think his problem is that he's actually seeing decimals after having used `Math.round()` ... Like my comments states above it's because he `/ 10` after the `Math.round()`

Comment: Don't work! I get 5.654.695.936

Comment: You have to apply `NumberFormat.format()` **after** the last calculation!!